# Visual Studio 2008 Pro - How to get a quick report about the number of files/classes/lines of code in a solution or project

Tags: visual-studio

How would you get a quick report about the number of files/classes/lines of code in a solution or project?

any one know of any free addons or hidden menus i dont seem to have found yet ?

Edit: It would also be cool if it could give a run down of amount of whitespace/comments compared to actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's code metrics require the Team Suite edition.  You might want to try [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Default.aspx), they have both open source/academic/trial (free) and professional ($$) editions.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything like that in the Professional version. You would have to bump up to the Developer or Team Suite version to get Code Metrics, which would get you what you want from the integrated tools

Beyond that, I think you have to go third party.

And my two cents worth is that you have to take metrics like that with a grain of salt anyway.